# Gradient as a Buttons BorderColor Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I am trying to Create a Button with Gradient Border Color in Xamarin Forms, i find the solution below to IOS but I can't find anything for android, can someone help me?

[Gradient as a Buttons BorderColor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427043/gradient-as-a-buttons-bordercolor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [PancakeView](https://github.com/sthewissen/Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView) which provides border with gradients, and add a touch gesture recognizer:

```xml
<yummy:PancakeView 
    BackgroundColor="#e2e885" 
    BorderGradientStops="{StaticResource Rainbow}" 
    HeightRequest="150" 
    CornerRadius="40,10,40,10" 
    BorderThickness="4" 
    BorderColor="#456287">
    <yummy:PancakeView.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnTapCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
    </yummy:PancakeView.GestureRecognizers>
    <Label Text="Button text" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
</yummy:PancakeView>
```